# Bootstrap grid dealing with large vs small content overlapping?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out why the height of my div is starting on a new line rather than wrapping with the `col-md-6`? I want it to where if content is larger than the other content, just wrap with it. But when I start a new `col-md-6` it's starting on a new line and the content that is smaller than the large content is leaving a bunch of empty space in the height.

Also please ignore the attributes I'm just curious about the fix for a grid solution. I'm just trying to achieve when content is larger than smaller content the next content wrap with it instead of starting on a new line.

It's hard to replicate the issue im trying to show so I have the issue I'm facing here in this codepen example:

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqgXMW)

Here is my code:

```html
 <link rel type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <form name="servicesform" action="test.cfm" method="post" class="form-inline">

  <!--- DEL --->
  <!--- FURNITURE --->
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <h2>FURNITURE:</h2>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="assureallfurnitureorder" class="form-check-input">
        <span>Assure all furniture on order is in unit</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="assureallfurnitureclean" class="form-check-input">
        <span>Assure all furniture is clean and in working order</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="assureallfurnituretouched" class="form-check-input">
     <span>Assure all furniture has been touched up</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="anybrokenitemshave" class="form-check-input">
     <span>Any broken items have been reported immediately through "5-STAR"</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!---PRODUCT --->
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <h2>PRODUCT:</h2>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="assureallnewproduct" class="form-check-input">
        <span>test</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="assureallfurniturecleanworking" class="form-check-input">
        <span>test</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="setuptvs" class="form-check-input">
     <span>test</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="arrangefurnitureapp" class="form-check-input">
     <span>test</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ensureartwork" class="form-check-input">
     <span>test</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="allbedsaremade" class="form-check-input">
     <span>test</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="decosetup" class="form-check-input">
     <span>test</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="welcomepack" class="form-check-input">
     <span>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="moveinshouldbe" class="form-check-input">
     <span>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going</span>
      </label>
    </div>     
  </div>

  <!---PRODUCT --->
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <h2>PRODUCT:</h2>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="assureallnewproduct" class="form-check-input">
        <span>test</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="assureallfurniturecleanworking" class="form-check-input">
        <span>test</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="setuptvs" class="form-check-input">
     <span>test</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="arrangefurnitureapp" class="form-check-input">
     <span>Arrange furniture appropriately</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ensureartwork" class="form-check-input">
     <span>test</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="allbedsaremade" class="form-check-input">
     <span>test</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="decosetup" class="form-check-input">
     <span>test</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="welcomepack" class="form-check-input">
     <span>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="moveinshouldbe" class="form-check-input">
     <span>test</span>
      </label>
    </div>     
  </div>

      <!---PRODUCT --->
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <h2>PRODUCT:</h2>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="assureallnewproduct" class="form-check-input">
        <span>test</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="assureallfurniturecleanworking" class="form-check-input">
        <span>test</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="setuptvs" class="form-check-input">
     <span>test</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="arrangefurnitureapp" class="form-check-input">
     <span>Arrange furniture appropriately</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ensureartwork" class="form-check-input">
     <span>test</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="allbedsaremade" class="form-check-input">
     <span>test</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="decosetup" class="form-check-input">
     <span>test</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="welcomepack" class="form-check-input">
     <span>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="moveinshouldbe" class="form-check-input">
     <span>test</span>
      </label>
    </div>     
  </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: You seem to have missed one of the fundamental aspects of Bootstrap; that `columns` show be wrapped in `rows`. Because each row contains 12 columns, two `col-md-6` constitute one row. That is to say, your next `col-md-6` will be on a new row. If you want the next row's elements to be directly below the **shorter** of the two columns (without the padding), Bootstrap probably isn't the best framework for you to achieve that.

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to have it to where if the rows elements are shorter of the two columns the next row wrap with the shorter row. Bootstrap isn't a good solution for that?

Comment: hmm maybe Flex box is an better solution to what I need then.